# Strange font rendering after installing Dolphin

Tags: 14.04, kde, fonts, thunderbird, antialiasing

After installing and testing KDE's Dolphin for a while the font rendering (or maybe anti-aliasing?) in non-GTK (e.g. Chrome and Thunderbird) programs looks strange. Playing around with QT(4) and KDE settings didn't help.

Example of right render in Nautilus and the wrong in Thunderbird: 
[image: Example of bad rendering]

Comment: I half remember something similar --- it was something that created a `~/.fontconfig/*` file and getting rid of it solved the problem. But I am not sure --- so a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Deleting a file called fonts.conf with wrong AA instructions helped to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Rmano guessed I had to delete **~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf** which included (wrong) settings for the antialiasing of fonts. Any problematic program started after deleting that file, rendered the fonts right again.

Answer (score 0):

If the config file mentioned in [Marvin Janosch's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/546404/166291) doesn't exist, configuration can also be adjusted using [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/).

Go to **Fonts**, and under **Appearance**, adjust **Hinting**.