# Ubuntu rendering fonts in a weird manner

Tags: firefox, compiz, fonts, evolution, synapse

I currently have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.

The fonts were working fine so far, but have suddenly started rendering in a weird manner. Either they're being chopped off or are removing any preceding margins. I've noticed this issue on Firefox and Evolution.

I had installed a bleeding edge version of Synapse. However, on uninstalling, there didn't seem to be any improvement. I had also installed Compiz Config Manager and plugins. Additionally, I had change my systemwide default language and installed a few additonal languages.

What seems to be the issue? Is there a conflict?

Comment: See if http://askubuntu.com/questions/545952/strange-font-rendering-after-installing-dolphin can help --- seems similar.

Comment: I had a nastier problem with fonts a few years ago where the login screen had huge unreadable fonts. Until it got fixed by updates much later, I got around it by adding the `nomodeset` flag to my kernel boot command. If the suggestion from @Rmano doesn't work, then you might try that. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 I'm not sure if this would help you or not, but setting it once using the grub edit boot command line option will tell you if it helps.